# swipeWithEvent equivalent for Lion

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-lion

In snow leopard there is a gesture recognizer for swipe events:

```
- (void)swipeWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
    CGFloat x = [event deltaX];

    if (x != 0) {
        (x > 0) ? [self goBack] : [self goForward];
    }
}
```

Is there an equivalent that detects two fingers swipe like the Safari app is doing for navigating pages in Lion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up extrapolating the useful info from [this commit](http://codereview.chromium.org/7465072/) and implement it in my own project:

```
    #define kSwipeMinimumLength 0.3

    - (void)swipeWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
    CGFloat x = [event deltaX];
    //CGFloat y = [event deltaY];

    if (x != 0) {
        (x > 0) ? [self goBack] : [self goForward];
    }
}

- (void)beginGestureWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event
{
    NSSet *touches = [event touchesMatchingPhase:NSTouchPhaseAny inView:nil];

    self.twoFingersTouches = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    for (NSTouch *touch in touches) {
        [twoFingersTouches setObject:touch forKey:touch.identity];
    }
}

- (void)endGestureWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event
{
    if (!twoFingersTouches) return;

    NSSet *touches = [event touchesMatchingPhase:NSTouchPhaseAny inView:nil];

    // release twoFingersTouches early
    NSMutableDictionary *beginTouches = [twoFingersTouches copy];
    self.twoFingersTouches = nil;

    NSMutableArray *magnitudes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSTouch *touch in touches) 
    {
        NSTouch *beginTouch = [beginTouches objectForKey:touch.identity];

        if (!beginTouch) continue;

        float magnitude = touch.normalizedPosition.x - beginTouch.normalizedPosition.x;
        [magnitudes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:magnitude]];
    }

    // Need at least two points
    if ([magnitudes count] < 2) return;

    float sum = 0;

    for (NSNumber *magnitude in magnitudes)
        sum += [magnitude floatValue];

    // Handle natural direction in Lion
    BOOL naturalDirectionEnabled = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"com.apple.swipescrolldirection"] boolValue];

    if (naturalDirectionEnabled)
        sum *= -1;

    // See if absolute sum is long enough to be considered a complete gesture
    float absoluteSum = fabsf(sum);

    if (absoluteSum < kSwipeMinimumLength) return;

    // Handle the actual swipe
    if (sum > 0) 
    {
        [self goForward];
    } else
    {
        [self goBack];
    }


}
```

It's not 100% tested, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks, this has helped me. The only problem I have is the MAgic Mouse. For some reason it has 0 touches when using it, so your method can't work. Any ideas?

Comment: The Magic Mouse sends scroll events. Check out https://github.com/Kapeli/SwipableWebView/blob/master/Swipable%20WebView/DHSwipeClipView.m for an implementation that works with both the Magic Mouse and the trackpad.

Comment: Oscar - GREAT FIND! Thank you, this helped me out. It works well, just a few comments... 1. I removed the natural direction portion of this snippet. 2. I set the swipe min length to 0.3 3. I implemented this as subclass on WebView, but will likely move it as a category on WebView. Again great find Oscar, thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. See the [AppKit release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Cocoa/AppKit.html). (You should read them from end to end regardless.)

Comment: Can you elaborate in which section to look at? I'm not using a scroll view (I've saw examples for that in the release notes)

Comment: Meaningless! I read through the AppKit release notes and understood a two finger swipe is a scroll event. That is one thing, how to handle it is something different which is what the questions' intent was.